# Embed ActionScript (AS) into flash

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I've never dealt with Flash/ActionScript, so please bear with me.
Mostly, I'm a bit confused.
I've done many work with Java/C as well as HTML/Javascript.

I am working with a designer who provides me with flash files (.swf).
From my point of view, it's a simple "mock" to which I need to embed a single object.
This object is a TextBox, with which the user interacts.
I need to be able to

1. Insert such a TextBox to a Flash file
2. Retrieve text upon key event
3. process it, and return it to the TextBox

As I understood from other posts, I'll be working with AS, right?
How do I embed such an object to an existing Flash file?
Being that the graphical part is over once I have the TextBox, would I need any fancy IDE for that?
What IDE is that (I usually work with Eclipse)?

One last note:
I am working with that designer, so I have access to all her creation process.
She does not know code, nor do I think she'll get it.
I would much prefer to give her as little headache as possible (e.g. just instruct her how to export the files to me from her Adobe Flash CS5 studio).

Many thanks,
Trev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't edit the .swf file, it is a compiled/exported/built/runnable file. If you can get a .fla file, a source file, from the designer, you can use that in compiling a new swf. Code for the functionality goes in one or more .as ActionScript files.

I'm no Java expert, so someone correct me if I'm wrong here, but I believe you can think of the .as source files like .java files, where you declare one class per file, and the .swf file is more like a .jar file, that can be run by the Flash Player. The .fla file, that the designer can supply, is another kind of source file, used for graphics and frame-by-frame animations.

For using Eclipse for Flash and Flex development, here is a tutorial on how to set up Eclipse to use the Flex SDK, and thereby also ActionScript:

http://www.seanhsmith.com/2010/03/29/flex-for-free-setting-up-the-flex-4-sdk-with-eclipse-ide/

An other alternative, if you don't want to buy Flash Builder (that is based on Eclipse) or Flash CS5 from Adobe, is the free and open source [FlashDevelop](http://www.flashdevelop.org/) (if you use Windows).

If what you need to do is only a one time thing, a short foray into Flash/ActionScript development, you may get by using the 45 day trial version of Flash Builder or Flash CS5.

Comment: Lars, your answer seems very helpful. What should I tell the designer to do/click in order to get the derived .fla file?

Comment: the .fla is the "raw" flash document, much like a .psd from photoshop or a .doc from word. the designer just needs to send you that file.

Comment: @David: the fla file is compiled by the Flash IDE and produces a swf file. You need some kind of conventions with the designer in order to use the swf. Since it seems that he provided a layout and all elements are placed on the stage as they should go. In your case, he should place the TextField and name it, then you can load the swf and access the TextField by referencing its name.

Answer (score 0):

```
designer should give you a *.fla file that can open with Adobe flash CS5. 
when you open the fla file in flash cs5 , there many controls you can use
 as well as TextBox, I think it must be a TextInput control. just drag it
 from the component window to any where you want. you need give a instance 
 name to this TextInput then you can control it with Actionscript code.
 if only swf file , you can use 'Sothink SWF Decompiler' to decompiler it 
 to Fla file.
```